# Change opacity of URL image in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a few lines of code that add a plant into my canvas game:

```
function drawPlant() {
    base_image = new Image();
    base_image.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/xOupnQp.png';
    if (treeLoaded) {
        ctx.drawImage(base_image, 20, 333, 60, base_image.height * (60/base_image.width));
    }
    else {
    base_image.onload = function(){
        treeLoaded = true;
    };
}
```

This puts the image into my game. However, I also want to make it faded out a bit. Could I use GlobalAlpha for this? And if so, how do I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `globalAlpha` is a good choice. It takes a value in the range [0, 1].

**For example:**

(example also corrects loading pattern)

```
function drawPlant() {
    base_image = new Image();
    base_image.onload = function(){
        treeLoaded = true;
        ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5; // 50% opacity
        ctx.drawImage(this, 20, 333, 60, base_image.height * (60/base_image.width));
        ctx.globalAlpha = 1; // normal full opacity
    };
    base_image.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/xOupnQp.png';
}
```

You might want to consider a callback too as loading images happens asychronously, for example, a modified example with callback-ability could look like:

```
function drawPlant(callback) {
    base_image = new Image();
    base_image.onload = function(){
        treeLoaded = true;
        ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5; // 50% opacity
        ctx.drawImage(this, 20, 333, 60, base_image.height * (60/base_image.width));
        ctx.globalAlpha = 1;  // normal full opacity
        callback(this);       // invoke callback with image as argument
    };
    base_image.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/xOupnQp.png';
}
```

Then:

```
drawPlant(function(img) {
    // continue from here...
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I also have one more function that is animated. http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=8ZYV9DN5
Could you explain how I could make that one transparent too?

Comment: I went to create a new question and was met with this message:
We are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.
Is there any other way I can explain this to you? My entire game is here: http://www.codecademy.com/IStoleThePies/codebits/UJFpg4/edit

Comment: @IStoleThePies if you have problem with your account contact a moderator or ask for help on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/). Open a new post for new question. If the answer solved your problem consider accepting it to close this post.